# Writing Digg like system in django/python

Tags: python, django, digg

I am tying to write a digg , hackernews , http://collectivesys.com/ like application where users submit something and other users can vote up or down , mark items as favorite ect . 
I was just wondering if there are some open source implementations  django/python that i could use as starting point , instead of reinventing the wheel  by starting from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a close look at the [django-voting project](http://code.google.com/p/django-voting/wiki/RedditStyleVoting) on Google Code.

They claim to be an django implementation of "Reddit Style Voting"

Comment: Nice. Looks like what I am after

Answer (score 6):

Check out [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) and [Django Pluggables](http://djangoplugables.com/) for some pre-made Django apps to help you out.

Comment: Pinax looks promising . Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[reddit](http://reddit.com) is [open source](https://github.com/reddit/reddit), written mostly in python. Apart from the code, there might be some algorithms you may find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Though not written in django, [reddit](http://reddit.com) is written in python and is open source.  From [the code](http://code.reddit.com/) you could get some ideas and see how they overcame certain hurdles etc.  They've open sourced everything bar their antispam measures.